# asp.net ajax ratings control not working properly

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I need to make users rating system for which I am using ajax rating control. I have defined all it's css still it's not working properly. Like There is 5 star rating now if user clicks on any star till that star color should get change but here it is not working like that. Also on whichever star I hover mouse it shows tooltip 1. Below is my code.

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="ratings.aspx.vb" Inherits="ratings" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/fonts/fontawesome/fontawesome.css" />
    <style type="text/css">
        .star:before {
            color: #f00;
            font-size:2em
        }

        .empty:before {
            color: #ccc;
            font-size:2em
        }

        .WaitingStar:before {
            color: #ed2025;
            font-size:2em
        }

        .FilledStar:before {
            color: #ffcc00;
            font-size:2em
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="sc1" runat="server"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <div>
        <asp:Rating ID="Rating2" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" StarCssClass="star fa fa-star" EmptyStarCssClass="empty fa fa-star" WaitingStarCssClass="WaitingStar fa fa-star" FilledStarCssClass="FilledStar fa fa-star" MaxRating="5" CurrentRating="1">
        </asp:Rating>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Like in above screenshot you can see my cursor is on 3rd star hence colored didn't changes as well as tooltip is showing 1 instead of 3. For better understanding you can also refer this page I uploaded http://foxboxrewards.com/ratings.aspx[image]

Web.config (When error comes)

```
<trust level="Full" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <authentication mode="None"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    <machineKey validationKey="B4973B4FA7A0A4F212F7264B3D5AB728CC59827D255087B064E5546E9C4D6D02F9D59224FE6EB33716C21CE6D2ADD174B9B4AEEBEFDA22D860643EDABB71A423" decryptionKey="DC2B319841AEF51E81AFC4135BAF9A5C2B010DAB2C97F9983CFF8CA2146E61B0" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
    <pages validateRequest="false">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity"/>
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>
```

Web.config (Working)

```
<authentication mode="None"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity"/>
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in the Chrome Developer Tools console? Press F12.

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez Yes. I see lot of errors. Posting screenshot in my question. Please have a look

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez But I don't understand why this errors are coming & how can I fix it

Comment: The errors you see are related to AjaxExtensions. First run the page without the `asp:Rating` control. Check for errors.

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez I noticed if I changed some code in web.config file then this error gone away. Posting web.config code in my question. Please have a look.

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez so by just removing machinkey from web.config it started working. But does it matter having machine key in web.config to ajax extentions?

Comment: **machineKey Element.-** Configures algorithms and keys to use for encryption, decryption, and validation of forms-authentication data and view-state data, and for out-of-process session state identification. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8h3skw9(v=vs.100).aspx. This configuration probably causes conflicts in your AjaxControlToolkit control.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the below steps that made the application working:-
1. install the ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit run the [new installer from DevExpress.com:](https://go.devexpress.com/AjaxControlToolkit_GitHub_DevExpressPage.aspx) 
[image]

2. Accept the License Agreement and the AJAX Control Toolkit will be installed for each supported Microsoft Visual Studio version installed 
[image]

3. After this Ajax Control toolkit will be available in your Toolbox.

4. Here is my .aspx page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="SO.Default" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="Content/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style type="text/css">
        .star:before {
            color: #f00;
            font-size:2em
        }

        .empty:before {
            color: #ccc;
            font-size:2em
        }

        .WaitingStar:before {
            color: #ed2025;
            font-size:2em
        }

        .FilledStar:before {
            color: #ffcc00;
            font-size:2em
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>
        <ajaxToolkit:Rating ID="Rating2" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" 
            StarCssClass="star fa fa-star" EmptyStarCssClass="empty fa fa-star" 
            WaitingStarCssClass="WaitingStar fa fa-star" FilledStarCssClass="FilledStar fa fa-star" MaxRating="5" CurrentRating="1">
        </ajaxToolkit:Rating>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Note - I am using asp:ScriptManager tag from AJAX Extensions. Usually if are using .NET Framework 4.0 or above its better to use asp:ScriptManager than ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager 
When you drag and drop ajaxToolkit:Rating from the toolbox @Register directive is automatically added for you.
When I pressed ctrl + F5 everything is working fine

Comment: I don't think you have read my entire post. This is not very simple problem or problem coming because my project missing ajax extension. All is there.

Comment: @SUN   "There is 5 star rating now if user clicks on any star till that star color should get change but here it is not working like that" - **but it is working in the solution I provided.**                                                       "Also on whichever star I hover mouse it shows tooltip 1. " - **but it is working in the solution I provided.**